# Joining unrelated tables via JPQL

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, jpql

I have the following query which works. All the tables in this query have relations in some way.

```
@Repository(value = "ARepository")
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<CardEntity, String> {
    @Query("SELECT xref.shortUtlTx FROM CardEntity card " +
            "JOIN card.apexUrlCrossRef xref " +
            "JOIN xref.sampleProdOffer offer " +
            "WHERE xref.apexCard.cardNumber = :cardNum " +
            "AND offer.apexeeOfferId = :myCode"
    )
    List<String> getAllValues(@Param("cardNum") String cardNum, @Param("myCode") String myCode);
}
```

But I also wish to join another table (Entity name -> UrlCountEntity) to this query but that table has no relation to the other tables in this query. Is there a way I could do this?

Based on reading a blog, I tried the following but throws errors. 
Added this line to the query:

> AND EXISTS (SELECT referCount FROM UrlCountEntity referCount WHERE
>   referCount.url.urlTx = xref.shortUtlTx)

```
@Repository(value = "ARepository")
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<CardEntity, String> {

    @Query("SELECT xref.shortUtlTx FROM CardEntity card " +
            "JOIN card.apexUrlCrossRef xref " +
            "JOIN xref.sampleProdOffer offer " +
            "WHERE xref.apexCard.cardNumber = :cardNum " +
            "AND offer.apexeeOfferId = :myCode " +
            "AND EXISTS (SELECT referCount FROM UrlCountEntity referCount WHERE referCount.url.urlTx = xref.shortUtlTx)"
    )
    List<String> getAllValues(@Param("cardNum") String cardNum, @Param("myCode") String myCode);

}
```

Error as follows:

> Method threw
>   'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException'
>   exception.
>
> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-and-hibernate/): 
Using Hibernate 5.1 or newer you can join two unrelated tables via JQPL same way you would do it in SQL:

```
SELECT first
FROM First first JOIN
    Second second ON first.property = second.property
WHERE first.property = :param
```

So you would need to change your query to something like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT xref.shortUtlTx FROM CardEntity card " +
        "JOIN card.apexUrlCrossRef xref " +
        "JOIN xref.sampleProdOffer offer " +
        "JOIN UrlCountEntity referCount ON referCount.url.urlTx = xref.shortUtlTx" +
        "WHERE xref.apexCard.cardNumber = :cardNum " +
        "AND offer.apexeeOfferId = :myCode")
List<String> getAllValues(@Param("cardNum") String cardNum, @Param("myCode") String myCode);
```